# Add button in Magento2 Edit Form

Tags: magento2, adminform

i create field product ulr and create button in my custom module in magento2 admin now i want if we write producturl in the text box and presss button its redirect to the url how i do that.

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'product_url', 'text', [
    'name' => 'product_url',
    'label' => __('Product Url'),
    'title' => __('Product Url'),
    'required' => true,
    'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
);
    $fieldset->addField('registered', 'button', array(
    'label' => __('Test url'),

    'name'  => 'registered',
    'class' => 'form-button',
    'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/*/registeremail')}')",
));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get the url value and redirect to that page using `RedirectFactory`.

create a class in `Vendor/Module/Controller/Index`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $redirectFactory,

class Result extends Action {

   protected $resultPageFactory;
   protected $redirectFactory
   public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory, RedirectFactory $redirectFactory)
   {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->redirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $url = $this->getRequest()->getParam('url');
        $result = $this->redirectFactory->create()
        ->setPath($url);
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: i want this by usin js